# Properly link an url in Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, urls

How to properly link an url in Bibliography?

I've tried this:

```
@book{wiki4,
    label    = {Razor},
    author   = {Wikipedia's collaborators},
    date     = {2014-01-01},
    url      = {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Razor_view_engine},
    urldate  = {2014-04-12}
}
```

But, `urldate` doesn't work. Is there any other format allowing that, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you please edit your post and add a fully compilable (minimum working) example? It would a great starting point for solvers.

Comment: Are you loading `hyperref`?

Comment: @Malipivo, I've updated my post.

Comment: @cfr, yes, you'll find its code in the posted code.

Comment: I get no errors (once I corrected a couple of typos in the code), and I get a printed and functional URL and date.

Comment: Works fine here, too. Although you probably need `babel` to get the date formatted correctly.

Comment: @PaulStanley, but the text is in french, it's supposed to display `visité` and not `visited`!

Comment: @cfr, but the text is in french, it's supposed to display `visité` and not `visited`!

Comment: As I said, you need `babel` for (pdf)LaTeX. Maybe `polyglossia` for Lua/XeLaTeX. Either way, you need something to handle anything other than US English.

Comment: @PaulStanley, Paul I've posted the full code that I'm currently using and that when I run it, [I get this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/abetv.png).

Comment: Load `hyperref` *after* `biblatex`.

Comment: Always make sure your code compiles *before* posting!

Comment: Your example is becoming less and less minimal. When you are having trouble, you *simplify* your code until you find the problem. Don't keep adding to it or you will never figure it out. For example, it would be helpful to know if my examples give you the expected results i.e. if you copy, paste and compile those examples, do they work? If not, we would know it was something about your config/installation. As it is, we don't know if it is that or some additional complication in the code you are testing.

Comment: @cfr, yes your example is working fine when I compile it. But after the edition of it, I get the same misdisplay.

Comment: @PaulStanley Do you by any chance use MiKTeX? I was wondering if the code posted in my answer also worked for you as I'm suspecting the remaining issue is due to an outdated version of `biber`/`biblatex`. However, I don't have MiKTeX (or Windows) so cannot be of great use to the OP at this point.

Comment: @cfr I use TeXlive and MiKTeX depending where I am. You answer works on MiKTeX.

Comment: @PaulStanley Thanks for checking that. Probably the OP just needs to run the updates in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works fine. It has nothing to do with `urldate`. You just haven't specified anything to handle any language other than American English.

If you are compiling with LaTeX or pdfLaTeX, you should use `babel`. You also want to use the `T1` encoding for French. I've added `inputenc` with `utf8` so you can type accented characters such as `ŵ` directly. If you don't want that, just comment it out. Finally `csquotes` is recommended for use with `biblatex` etc.

```
\documentclass[12pt,french]{report}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{wikis.bib}
@book{wiki4,
        label    = {Razor},
        author   = {Wikipedia's collaborators},
        date     = {2014-01-01},
        url      = {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Razor_view_engine},
        urldate  = {2014-04-12}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[unicode=true,
bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=false,
breaklinks=true,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
{hyperref}

\addbibresource{wikis.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography in French]

## Full code

This is based on the full example you added to your question. As posted, that code would not compile so the following is not identical with what you posted. Rather, it is minimally modified to compile. The modified version works fine for me, including the hyperlink, date formatting etc.

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,french]{report}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in,headheight=12pt,headsep=25pt,footskip=30pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[bottom,hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}% recommended in output (biblatex)
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}

\skip\footins 1cm

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{% adjust the template for the label based on the default one - requires biber
  \labelelement{%
    \field[final]{shorthand}% if shorthand specified, use it
    \field{label}% if label specified, use it author's name
  }
  \labelelement{%
    \literal{,\addhighpenspace}% add comma
  }
  \labelelement{%
  \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}% take the rightmost 2 numbers from the year
  }
}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{wikis.bib}
@book{wiki4,
        label    = {Razor},
        author   = {Wikipedia's collaborators},
        date     = {2014-01-01},
        url      = {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Razor_view_engine},
        urldate  = {2014-04-12}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[unicode=true,bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=false,breaklinks=true,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=false]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{wikis.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\end{document}
```

### Notes

- If you wish to use `\MakeAutoQuote*{“}{”}` then you need to specify the `utf8` input encoding. I've therefore deleted the line setting active quotes in my example.
- Only load `hyperref` *once* and load it *after* `biblatex`. I've deleted the first invocation (before `biblatex`), leaving only the second.
- I also tidied up some erroneous line breaks but those could be artefacts of copy-paste rather than a function of the original code.
- *Always look at the output* when you have trouble - not just the final document or lack of one. Often, this means switching to the command line to compile. In this case, compilation stopped at least 3 times with errors, several of which told you exactly what was wrong. (Though at least one was much less obvious.) The `.log` file is another useful resource in these cases.
- Another strategy is to selectively comment out parts of your code until you find what is causing the trouble. Combining this with examination of the output and `.log` was especially useful in this case.

[image: Bibliography]

Comment: But, at the compiling biber time, [I get this only warning](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HtkOw.png).

Comment: @Djouma Most of that is just info. The warning is probably important, though. It looks as if your version of the `biblatex` `.bcf` is not what `biber` expects. Sometimes this happens if you've just updated and a rerun of `pdflatex` solves the issue. However, it is finding a *newer* version than expected. Do you have more than one installation of TeX?

Comment: @Djouma Please try my examples *as posted* and report your results. This won't solve the problem you are actually facing but it is a crucial step towards diagnosing it. Adding greater and greater complexity to your example is just adding more and more unknown factors.

Comment: Have you seen my edited posted code? I've just added a few lines before `\begin{document}`, after doing that, `pdfLaTeX/Biber` are not building the bibliography section correctly.

Comment: @Djouma Does it work without that? If so, comment out sections until you identify the culprit. (There are more than 'a few' lines added.)

Comment: yes your example is working fine when I compile it. But after the edition of it, I get the same  misdisplay.

Comment: @Djouma So do the selective commenting. I can't because your current code uses a bib file I don't have.

Comment: @Djouma That also gives the expected output here. The line-breaking is a bit ugly but the basic formatting and link are fine. Run exactly the code you posted. If that works, try to figure out which entry in the bib file is causing the problem. If the bib file is not very large, you could post it. Otherwise, try selectively adding blocks of entries into the `filecontents` environment until you reproduce the error.

Comment: Ok. I've added the full .bib file to the main post. Has this worked for you ?

Comment: @Djouma That also works fine for me. The dates are formatted as e.g. '12 avr. 2014' and the URL comes last. The link works fine. (I tested the `Razor` example.) So there are a couple of possibilities: (1) something about your particular configuration (look at the `.log` and/or output for errors/warnings) or (2) that your installation is out of date. You have `biber` 1.5 whereas mine is 1.8. I think (2) is quite likely so I'd recommend updating your installation of TeX if nothing suggests itself in the `.log`.

Comment: how to update biber?

Comment: @Djouma Best to update your TeX installation since you'll need the matching version of `biblatex`, too. How did you install TeX? (TeX Live? MiKTeX? Package manager? Upstream?)

Comment: @Djouma Do you have the latest version and is there a way of updating packages in MiKTeX? I've addressed a comment on your question to the other commenter there in the hopes that they may be using MiKTeX (or at least know something more about it). I believe that the latest version is 2.9 but beyond that, I'm pretty much out of my depth, I'm afraid.

Comment: I've MikTeX 2.9 version